# Helmholtz decomposition of $v\in (L^2(\Omega))^3$

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, vector-analysis, lp-spaces, potential-theory

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^3$ be a bounded domain with Lipschitz boundary $\partial\Omega$ and outward unit normal $n$.

I want to study the characterize whether a vector function defined on $\Omega$ admits a scalar potential or a vector potential.

Let's introduce the following spaces of *harmonic fields*
$$
H(m;\Omega)=\{v\in (L^2(\Omega))^3:curl(v)=0\,\,\text{in}\,\Omega, div(v)=0\,\,\text{in}\,\Omega, v\cdot n =0\,\,\text{on}\,\partial\Omega\}
$$

$$
H(e;\Omega)=\{v\in (L^2(\Omega))^3:curl(v)=0\,\,\text{in}\,\Omega, div(v)=0\,\,\text{in}\,\Omega, v\times n =0\,\,\text{on}\,\partial\Omega\}
$$

The following decompositions hold.

**Theorem 1:** *Any $v\in (L^2(\Omega))^3$ can be decomposed into
$$
v=curl(Q)+\nabla\psi+\rho
$$
where
 - each term is orthogonal to the others
 - if $curl(v)=0$ in $\Omega$, then $Q=0$ in $\Omega$
 - if $div(v)=0$ in $\Omega$ and $v\cdot n=0$ on $\partial\Omega$, then $\nabla\psi=0$ in $\Omega$
 - if $v\perp H(m;\Omega)$, then $\rho=0$ in $\Omega$
 - $Q$ is solution to
 $$
\begin{cases} 
   curl curl (Q)= curl(v) & \text{in } \Omega \\
   div(Q)=0       & \text{in } \Omega\\
   Q\times n=0 & \text{on } \partial\Omega\\
   Q\perp H(e;\Omega)
  \end{cases}
$$
 - $\psi$ is solution to
 $$
\begin{cases} 
   \Delta\psi= div(v) & \text{in } \Omega \\
   \nabla\psi\cdot n= v\cdot n & \text{on } \partial\Omega
  \end{cases}
$$
 - $\rho$ is the $L^2$-orthogonal projection of $v$ onto $H(m;\Omega)$*

**Theorem 2:** *Any $v\in (L^2(\Omega))^3$ can be decomposed into
$$
v=curl(A)+\nabla\phi+\eta
$$
where
 - each term is orthogonal to the others
 - if $curl(v)=0$ in $\Omega$ and $v\times n=0$ on $\partial\Omega$, then $A=0$ in $\Omega$
 - if $div(v)=0$ in $\Omega$, then $\nabla\phi=0$ in $\Omega$
 - if $v\perp H(e;\Omega)$, then $\eta=0$ in $\Omega$
 - $A$ is solution to
 $$
\begin{cases} 
   curl curl (A)= curl(v) & \text{in } \Omega \\
   div(A)=0       & \text{in } \Omega\\
   A\cdot n = 0   & \text{in } \Omega\\
   A\times n=v\times n & \text{on } \partial\Omega\\
   Q\perp H(m;\Omega)
  \end{cases}
$$
 - $\phi$ is solution to
 $$
\begin{cases} 
   \Delta\phi= div(v) & \text{in } \Omega \\
   \phi=0 & \text{on } \partial\Omega
  \end{cases}
$$
 - $\eta$ is the $L^2$-orthogonal projection of $v$ onto $H(e;\Omega)$*

Now, the following theorems follow easily.

**Theorem 3**: *Let $v\in (L^2(\Omega))^3.$ There exists a scalar potential $\psi$ if and only if $curl(v)=0$ in $\Omega$ and $v\perp H(m;\Omega)$.*

**Theorem 4**: *Let $v\in (L^2(\Omega))^3.$ There exists a vector potential $A$ if and only if $div(v)=0$ in $\Omega$ and $v\perp H(e;\Omega)$.*

From the first two theorems it's really immediate to deduce the latter two. My problem is to remember the first the two results. Do you have any suggestions? Why $Q$, $\phi$, $A$ and $\phi$ are defined like that?

(I'm looking for a intuitive/heuristic motivation)

Comment: LaTeX hint: \operatorname{div} -> $\operatorname{div}$.